# SSL certificate does not exist or is empty - WAMP

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wamp

When I run httpd -t I'm getting the error that my certificates don't exist - "does not exist or is empty". I've purchased the certificate and they are all setup correctly and I've checked the permissions with another server where it's fine which for both the folder and file are fine. The paths are definitely correct and the files are definitely not empty. I've rebooted the server and I still get the same error. I'm using ** WAMP ** if it makes a difference and help would be great. The question is why can WAMP not find my certificates? I am going to try upgrading to 2.5 (currently running WAMP 2.2) and see if that fixes it.

Unfortunately the latest WAMP still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple reason this was failing - extensions were turned off on the server so my files were actually certificate.crt.txt!! Hope that helps anyone else who has this issue.

Comment: It's old thread, but for me works without extension at all, e.g. `/etc/ssl/certs/example` instead of `/etc/ssl/certs/example.crt`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that SELINUX is set as permissive or disabled.

setenforce 0